# PHP MySQL error in statement

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO expense (date,desc,price,out,method) 
VALUES ('$time','$desc','$price','$out','$method');
```

What is wrong in the MySQL statement above? I have checked all the other stuff in my code but only this seems to be buggy.

I am passing this statement to mysql_query() function in PHP. It gives me an error and does not insert the data in the row.

All the variables above are also present.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: try to escape all the fields like `\`date\``

Comment: How about telling us the error message?

Comment: error in syntax near : desc,price,out,method) VALUES('1321196048','d','4','1','cash'

Comment: Please use prepared statements or escape your variables before using them in a query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is keyword in SQL (`` order by `key` desc ``). You cannot use barewords which are also keywords in SQL. In this case, you should escape desc with `` ` `` symbol (like `` `desc` ``). `date` is also keyword, but MySQL decided to allow it's incorrect usage because of common usage before making it keyword. But not every database engine allows this, so be careful.

But, it's good practice to actually quote all keys, even if it's not needed - this way you could protect against adding keywords in SQL which would break your queries.

- [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html)
- [List of keywords (in MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 3):

'date' is a MySQL keyword (for the date field type). You should enclose the field name with backticks like this:

```
INSERT INTO expense (`date`,desc,price,out,method)
```

(I think the other fields are fine, but you could add backticks to those as well if you like)